# How to add new test to already configured ctest suite?

Tags: unit-testing, boost, cmake, ctest

I have a c++ project which has a test suite with already configured scripts. if i run `ctest -V` it normally check all test available in a directory. 
I have written a new test and saved it in the same directory but if I run `ctest -V -R newtest` , i get the following message.

`UpdateCTestConfiguration`  from `:/home/user/project/DartConfiguration.tcl`

Constructing a list of tests

Done constructing a list of tests

Checking test dependency graph...

Checking test dependency graph end

No tests were found!!!

I could not find DartConfiguration.tc` file anywhere.
Please help , I am new to ctest or cmake.

Comment: Did you re-run CMake?

Comment: no, Sorry if it was necessary but is there a guide I can follow?

Comment: There is CTest documentation [here](http://public.kitware.com/Wiki/CMake#CTest).  Invoking `ctest -V` won't automatically cause CMake to re-run, and if you've added tests to your CMakeLists.txt, you need to re-run CMake for CTest to become "aware" of these.

Comment: You'll probably need to show us a small example that exhibits the issue.  Maybe you're not calling `include(ctest)`?

Comment: "cmake . " in the project directory did the job, cmakelists.txt is already configured to run tests in a particular directory. Now it is updated.